# How does the Resilient feat work?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

I'm a bit confused, because all my Player's Handbook says is 'Increase the chosen ability score by 1, to a maximum of 20'. Does this mean that I increase the ability score by 1 every level?

Answer (score 10):

No, it only increases that ability score by 1 once, as well as grants you proficiency with saves that use that ability score. If it granted you a increase each level, it would explicitly state that.

> #### Resilient
>
> Choose one ability score. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - Increase the chosen ability score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
> - You gain proficiency in saving throws using the chosen ability.

Answer (score 8):

No, the Resilient Feat does two things. It allows you to choose an Ability (Strength, Constitution, Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma.) to gain Proficiency with saving throws in, and it also allows you to increase that same Ability Score by 1 point, once at the time you take the feat, to a maximum (score) of 20.

> #### Resilient
>
> Choose one ability score. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - Increase the chosen ability score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
> - You gain proficiency in saving throws using the chosen ability.

What "to a maximum of 20 means", to answer your actual question, is that if you chose Constitution (for example) to gain Proficiency with Saving Throws in and increase the score by 1, but your Con score was ***already*** 20... then you can't increase it to 21 and the only benefit you would receive is the saving throw Proficiency.

Answer (score 0):

No the limit is 20 so if your ability score is already 20 you can't increase that anymore because that is the maximum for that feat. If it didn't give a cap well you could pick that ability score of choice.